# Reactjs - filter objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects. The Array and filter/map is below. Any idea why this doesnt return the link?

Array:

```
const icons = [
  {
    color: "Yellow",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png",
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Green",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png",
  },
  {
    color: "White",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_white.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Orange",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_orange.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Gray",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_gray.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Purple",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_purple.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Red",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Black",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_black.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Brown",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_brown.png",
  },
];
```

Filter Method:

```
 icon= {this.props.icons.filter(icons =>  icons.color.toLower == 'blue').map((icons) => {return icons.link})}/>
```

Entire Method:

```
renderMarker = this.props.mapData.map((item) => {
    
return item.dataset.map((item2) => {
  return item2.dataPoint.map((item3) => {
    return  <Marker
    onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
    name={item3.name}
    name2={item3._id}
    
    position={{ lat: item3.lat, lng:  item3.lng }}
    key={item3._id}
    icon= {this.props.icons.filter(icons =>  icons.color.toLower == 'blue').map((icons) => {return icons.link})}/>
  })
})
```

Comment: `toLower` should be `toLowerCase()`

Comment: `map` will return an array so you should check in `Marker` component.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the `.toLower` to `.toLowerCase()`.

I've used the `[0]` indexing to get the `link`. So you need to check the presence of a line in the `Marker` component.

```js
const result = icons
  .filter((icon) => icon.color.toLowerCase() === "blue")
  .map((icons) => {
    return icons.link;
  })[0];
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const icons = [
  {
    color: "Yellow",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png",
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Green",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png",
  },
  {
    color: "White",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_white.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Orange",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_orange.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Gray",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_gray.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Purple",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_purple.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Red",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Black",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_black.png",
  },
  {
    color: "Brown",
    link: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_brown.png",
  },
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ToLower does not exist in javascript. The correct method is ToLowerCase().
Your code is not clear though, you are using brackets in icon = {...} which means you are expecting a list to be returned.

If you are indeed expecting a list, then just change toLower to toLowerCase():

```
icon= {this.props.icons.filter(icon =>  icon.color.toLowerCase() == 'blue').map((icon) => {return icon.link})}
```

Otherwise, if you are certain you'll always have one unique result, as in one link only, then you don't have to use the map method.
Use "filter" method which returns a LIST, then get the first and only item, and access the "Link" property.

```
icon = this.props.icons.filter(icon => icon.color.toLowerCase() === "blue")[0].link;
```

PS: In your method, you are writing "icons" with an 's' inside the filter method:

icon = {this.props.icons.filter(icon**s**=> ....)

Just understand, that you receive each **individual** "icon" inside the filter method and not the whole list.